# "The me I want to be" phrase decomposition

Tags: translation

What is the difference between mentioned phrase and "I want to be the me"? Is it right to use both phrases in the spiritual growth context? I what parts we could deconstruct this phrase? Is the "I want to be" the attribute there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Me" is used in a very non-standard way here. It would often be stylized to show that it is unusual:

> the "Me" I want to be
>   the Me I want to be
>   the *me* I want to be

Your rearrangement *I want to be the me* is not correct. It doesn't make sense, and additionally it changed the original which was not a sentence into a complete sentence.

To aid you in understanding the original meaning, the best suggestion I can offer is to replace *me* with *person*. It will probably fit into the same contexts:

> the person I want to be

Does this make it easier to understand?

(I did not address your question about the "attribute," since I don't really know what that means.)

Comment: Yes, it's clear to me. Thank you. Could you explain what are the subject and the predicator in this simple sentence?

Comment: @Владимир - actually, it does not have a subject or predicate, since it is not a sentence. It is just a phase, which could function as the subject of a sentence, or as some other part.